# Dark Bar at the top of wordpress page can't be seen?

Tags: posts, php, options

I am new to wordpress and created a website as shown in the picture bellow. My webpage used to have a black bar at the top, which allowed me to insert "New Posts". (area shown in red circle). But this black bar is gone from my wordpress site now. Can you please tell me how can I get it back?

Image Link: http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/3443/2vj6.jpg

Comment: please check if you have `wp_footer()` in `footer.php` and `wp_head()` in `header.php` and in your profile under Users (in Dashboard) toolbar is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you have to check:

1. Check if `wp_footer` function is called in your footer.php file.
2. Check if the toolbar isn't disabled in your user settings.
3. Check if toolbar is showing after disabling all plugins you are using. If yes, then turn plugins on one by one to find out, which one of them is hiding the toolbar.
4. If disabling plugins didn't help, switch to some standard WP theme (Twenty...). If it helped, then it is some problem with your theme.

Comment: Thank you for telling me everything in details. chaning the theme and puting it back worked.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the "black bar at the top" is available for users who are logged in to your site. Select this in the WordPress Dashboard under "Users". Under the options for each user there is checkbox called "Toolbar". A check indicates "Show Toolbar when viewing site".